# How to send query request without refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe, woocommerce

I'm working with Woocommerce plugin in Wordpress. When you click add to cart button all it does is add this to the end of the url ?add-to-cart=4689 like so "http://example.com/?add-to-cart=4689" So whatever item id is in the url query gets added to the cart.

However I don't want to do a page refresh each time so right now I'm using  In order to add the item to the cart, but not refresh the page.

Is there anyway to send that page load request to url "http://example.com/?add-to-cart=4689" without using an iframe?

Comment: Do you mean like an ajax call?

Comment: @stevenmahieu I'm not sure what an ajax call is, but I'm looking for a way that will add an item to the cart as if he went to http://example.com/?add-to-cart=4689 so that it will add the item to the cart because of the query, without actually making the user go to that url

Comment: The description you give is a little vague. But I think what you are looking for is an ajax call.

Comment: @stevenmahieu I edited my post to try to make it more clear. Could you please show an example of how an ajax call would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be done using javascript.

The following should work with vanilla javascript.

```
<script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/?add-to-cart=4689');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            //add code to render what needs to be rendered
        }
        else {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
</script>
```

The item will be added like this but I presume that you won't see it in your basket until after you refreshed your page or re-rendered the component.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.